# chicken-scheme - how does one read all the lines passed in via standard input?

Tags: command-line-interface, chicken-scheme

I'm trying to read all the lines of whatever's passed in to a chicken-scheme script via standard in, and put them into a list, but I don't seem to be able to correctly determine when I've hit the end of the input. Another test script seemed to indicate that testing `(eof-object? results-of-last-read-line-call)` was a legit test, but in the example below it just sits there infinitely reading.

I've put together the following test script. I'm calling it with `cat some_file.txt | this_script.scm`

```
#! /usr/local/bin/csi -script

(define (read-from-stdin collection line)
  (if (eof-object? line) ; bad test? 
    collection
     (read-from-stdin (cons collection line) read-line)
  ) ; yes, i know atypical formatting. Done so you can see they're all there
)

(for-each print (read-from-stdin '() (read-line)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're passing the **procedure** `read-line` in the recursive call. This causes the test to always fail (because a procedure is never an `eof-object`). Instead, you probably want to **call** `read-line` and pass the line string:

```
(define (read-from-stdin collection line)
  (if (eof-object? line) ; the test is fine
      collection
      (read-from-stdin (cons collection line) (read-line))))

(for-each print (read-from-stdin  '() (read-line)))
```

You were also calling `cons` with the arguments reversed, so I fixed that as well. Perhaps this was an attempt at adding the lines in reverse?  Instead, you probably want to reverse the lines at the end, so you'd get

```
(for-each print (reverse (read-from-stdin  '() (read-line))))
```

Or of course you could call `(reverse collection)` in `read-from-stdin`.

Comment: thanks so much. i cleaned up my example to remove the `r3` and then removed the reference to it in your preamble.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use `read-lines` for this.
Here's your program written using it:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/csi -script
(import (chicken io))
(for-each print (read-lines))
```

Comment: This is not a complete and thorough answer of the sort we like to see on Stack Overflow. Please consult the [help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/answering) for guidance on answering questions, and I encourage you to come back and expand on this answer once you're done.

Comment: For reference, the answer originally read: "I like to use `read-lines` for this."  Don't really know what to add to that? It's exactly the procedure the asker was trying to write. Just use it or look it up. I added explicitly exactly what to write but... don't you guys think that's overkill?